# Intuitive notion of functoriality in topological data analysis

Tags: functors, topological-data-analysis

For school, we have to give a presentation about topological data analysis and I am in charge of motivating why topological data analysis is cool and useful. Most of what I say is based on "Topology and data" by Gunnar Carlsson. Specifically, I was planning to illustrate the four big advantages he lists by use of an example. However, I can't seem to really wrap my head around the fourth and seemingly most important advantage, namely functoriality.

I have followed a basic course on Category theory and Algebraic topology, but I am not sure what the biggest advantages of this functoriality in data analysis are.
So far, I think consistency in randomly sampled subsets is important (because of the example by Gunnar Carlson), but my intuition seems to lag behind.

So, what I am asking is if there is some unifying intuition for the advantages of functoriality in topological data analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading Robert Ghrist's Section [4.10](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Eghrist/EAT/EATchapter4.pdf) of his book, *Elementary Applied Topology*.

To give a brief excerpt from p. 75:

> There is hardly a more important feature of homology than this functoriality. One implication in the sciences is to *inference*. It is sometimes the case that what is desired is knowledge of the homology of an important but unobserved space $X$; the observed data comprises the homology of a pair of spaces $Y_1$, $Y_2$, which are related by a map $f: Y_1 \rightarrow Y_2$ ...
>
> [example] ... one can discern the presence of a true hole with *two* imprecise observations and a map between them.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't look at it yet, because I am busy with exams, but it looks promising.

Comment: @EmielLanckriet: Hope it helps and good luck with the exams!